Algolia issue with React Native
My InstantSearch is working fine and my data is getting index  from Firebase to Algolia by Cloud Function! I can see the changes in the Algolia dashboard immediately!
But when I add, update delete a document in firebase InfiniteHits is not showing to the new result.
I render all the records with a FlatList that uses "drag to load" functionality.
I have read this article but this dosent work for React Native.
https://support.algolia.com/hc/en-us/articles/11635994384913-How-to-Refresh-React-InstantSearch-Hooks-with-Infinite-Hits
I have tried everything I cannot manage to fix this issue in my React Native App :(
Right now I try to rerender the component but still doesn't work. It works when I completly reload the app..
Here is my code for the InfiniteHits component the renders all the records:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, FlatList } from "react-native";
import { useInfiniteHits, useInstantSearch } from "react-instantsearch-core";
import GridItem from "../screens/GridItem";
import SearchItem from "../screens/SearchItem";
import algoliasearch from "algoliasearch";

const InfiniteHits = ({ gridView, hitComponent: Hit, cache, ...props }) => {
  const [isRefreshing, setIsRefreshing] = useState(false);
  const [refreshKey, setRefreshKey] = useState(0); // New state for remounting component
  const { refresh } = useInstantSearch();
  const isGrid = gridView ? 2 : 1;

  const { hits, isLastPage, showMore } = useInfiniteHits({
    ...props,
    escapeHTML: false,
  });


  const handleRefresh = async () => {
    setIsRefreshing(true);

    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsRefreshing(false);
      setRefreshKey((prevKey) => prevKey + 1); // Increment key to trigger re-render
    }, 2000);
  };

  return (
    <View className="flex-1">
      <FlatList
        data={hits}
        key={refreshKey} // Use refreshKey to remount the component
        numColumns={isGrid}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.objectID}
        onEndReached={() => {
          if (!isLastPage) {
            showMore();
          }
        }}
        refreshing={isRefreshing}
        onRefresh={handleRefresh}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return item && gridView ? (
            <GridItem item={item} />
          ) : (
            <SearchItem item={item} />
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default InfiniteHits;

I tried everything I could find on the internet, nothing works.
Tried to rerender the component but that doesn't work either!
I have been stuck for a week.

It doesn't look like you're calling the refresh function you're retrieving from useInstantSearch()
useInfiniteHits is a hook rather than a function meaning it's state will persist through rerenders
You should just need to call refresh() in your handleRefresh function
